# Action Bar dropdown open and closed item styles

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to style the action bar list navigation such that it has white text in the closed state. When I've done that, though, it has turned **all** the text white, which doesn't work with the white dropdown.

Is there a way to style each individually? The docs are non-existant :(

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Add Custom Layout for your `Adapter`. in this i have created one layout inside that i have add one `TextView`. with `text color` and `background color`.

and set atapter like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(), R.layout.my_spinner_style, R.id.textView1,
                COUNTRIES);
```

here

`R.layout.my_spinner_style` is my custom layout.

`R.id.textView1` is textview id from `my_spinner_style.xml`.

**you can also applay your awn style inside TextView.** check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html) aretical.

check this code:

[image]

inside `onCreate`:

```
/** Create an array adapter to populate dropdownlist */
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(), R.layout.my_spinner_style, R.id.textView1,
                COUNTRIES);

        /** Enabling dropdown list navigation for the action bar */
        getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        /** Defining Navigation listener */
        ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition,
                    long itemId) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "You selected : " + COUNTRIES[itemPosition],
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        };

        /**
         * Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar
         */
        getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
```

my_spinner_style.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF00" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Similar to my comment on the other answer, I'm not trying to change the background on all of them, I want to change the text color depending on state, like the picture says...

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can do it programmatically (though I never tried it):

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuId, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.itemId).getActionView().setBackground(...)
  }
```

Comment: I don't need to change the background. I want to style the text color, in each state.

Comment: Put a custom actionView (setActionView) to be a TextView (or a Layout having a TextView somewhere inside). This is how you can control the text colour.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `Adapter` (which must by definition implement `SpinnerAdapter`) you have two callbacks that you can override. `getView` will be called for the "selected" item. `getDropDownView` will get called for the drop-down items. You can set your different text colors there.