# How to open custom layout dialog box below on click of button in android?

Tags: android

I want to make drop down custom dialog box below on click button.

[image]

**Click on counter button and layout will show below button.**

I seeing so many link but they open only list :-

[Action Bar dropdown open and closed item styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824793/action-bar-dropdown-open-and-closed-item-styles)

**New Quick Action package**

above link not use full to me.

**But when I'm using dialog box it appear front of button.**

so if you know then help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you are looking for by using

### getLocationOnScreen() api &

### PopUpWindow component.

An example code can be as follows.

```
int[] location = new int[2];
counterView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
final View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xxxx, null, false);
final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(mView, Width, Height, false);
popUp.setTouchable(true);
popUp.setFocusable(true);
popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popUp.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location[0], location[1]);
```

Comment: but one problem im facing it is if again click on counter button when popup is open it not working so can u tell me!!!!!

Comment: @Mani I've a drawable to edittext. I want the popup below that drawable image. How should I locate it.? Kindly help

Answer (score 2):

PopupWindow also has a method `showAsDropDown` which shows the popup as a dropdown below a view

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final View mView = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.drop_down_layout, null, false);
                final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow(mView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);
                popUp.setTouchable(true);
                popUp.setFocusable(true);
                popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);

            //Solution
                popUp.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.button));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to **wrap_content** in PopupWindow and get surprised cause it still works.

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(testView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, false);
```