# Android how to set popup window in honeycomb?

Tags: android, listview, popup, android-3.0-honeycomb

How to do this — does anyone have any idea of how to do this in tablets honeycomb?

`EDIT`= is it possible in android in possible how to do this.

[image]

and this [image]

`edit`:how load another activity(Mapview (or) Any other activity) with in the popup dialog. when i click button?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105875/how-to-open-custom-layout-dialog-box-below-on-click-of-button-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you basically have to create custom dialog boxes and implemnet as per your requirement

[Check this link for custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16354899/2345913)

Comment: already use custom dialog but not suitable for my requirement

Comment: what I meant was create complete layout inside a dialog. Customize its each component through layout.xml .  This may be a lot of task but you can develop a reusable theme-set dialog.

Comment: mapview activity display with in custom dialog is it possible

Comment: Yes, what you do in normal activity in setcontentView to display on screen, RIGHT.. The same logic follow. In here you do the same i.e. **dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);**

Comment: here iam useing tablet version with multi screen so dialog not good to show in my tablet version....